# Python multiprocessing loses activity without exiting file

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, unix, multiprocessing

I have a problem where my .py file, which uses maximum CPU through multiprocessing, **stops operating without exiting the .py file.**

I am running a heavy task that uses all cores in an old MacBook Pro (2012). The task runs fine at first, where I can visually see four python3.7 tasks populate the Activity Monitor window. However, after about 20 minutes, those four python3.7 disappear from the Activity Monitor.

The strangest part is the multiprocessing .py file is still operating, i.e. it never threw an uncaught exception nor exited the file.

Would you guys/gals have any ideas as to what's going on? My guess is 1) it's most likely an error in the script, and 2) the old computer is overheating.

Thanks!

Edit: Below is the multiprocess code, where the multiprocess function to execute is *func* with a list as its argument. I hope this helps!

```
import multiprocessing

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for i in range(24):
        pool.apply_async(func, args = ([], ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and add the code that you are using or we won't be able to help, as there are multiple ways to set up multiprocessing.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb, thanks for the heads up - attached is the multiprocessing code. I am still new to this concept.

Comment: I've added an answer that will probably clear up your problems. Since you removed some of what you are actually doing (the function) I kept it generic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a context manager to handle closing processes properly.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    with Pool() as p:
        result = p.apply_async(func, args = ([], ))
        print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I wasn't sure what you were doing with the `for i in range()` part.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems like only one process if running. I would like to run *func* as many times as possible in parallel with the list argument (the list content varies per run via randomization). The reason I put the for loop is to call apply_async many times to exercise more processors.

Comment: If you want to use more processors, you can do `Pool(5)` or similar for the number of processes that you want.

Comment: As far as randomness, and this list argument, without demonstrating further in your code on what you mean it will be hard for me to answer.